# i have an error: "Cannot read property 'style' of null"

Tags: javascript, function, properties

I have a problem with some Javascript. The code comes up with the following error.

> Cannot read property 'style' of null

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "100vw";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight = "100vh";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight= "0";
}
```

How do I fix this problem.

Comment: Can you paste your HTML? Looks like you do not have element with `mySidenav` or `main` id defined in HTML

Comment: first make sure, you find dom node

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)